# Trouble understanding $D_{2n} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have trouble understanding $D_{2n} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$ which was provided in a lecture

I understand that :

We want

$\phi: \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow Aut(\mathbb{Z}/n) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$.

$1$ must be sent to a generator $\phi(1)=-1$ works.

With this $\phi$, we have $D_{2n} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2$.

(up to here I understand)

With the operation, $(a,b)(c,d)= (a+(-1)^b c, b+d)$.

I have trouble understanding the jump where $[\phi(b)](c)=(-1)^b c$.

Why is this so?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say $\phi(1) = -1$, you really mean that $\phi(1)$ is the automorphism
$$
x \mapsto -x \text{ from } \mathbb{Z}/n \to \mathbb{Z}/n
$$
Hence,
$$
[\phi(1)](c) = -c
$$
Also, $\phi(0)$ is the identity map. In either case,
$$
[\phi(b)](c) = (-1)^bc
$$

Comment: Thank you. I see it's more clear now. Although would you be so kind to elaborate the the part where "you really mean" that $\phi(1)$ is $x \mapsto x$?

Comment: What I mean is, under the isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times} \cong Aut(\mathbb{Z}/n)$, the element $-1$ goes to the map $x\mapsto -x$.